# jQuery UI Multiple Droppable - drag whole div element & clone

Tags: jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

I've just started using jQuery UI to drag divs into a columns in a table. I have a couple different draggable divs with different background-colors and text inside them, and I need them to be able to dragged up to the drop area as a clone. This worked fine by using jQuery UI's example shopping cart code, but I've edited it so the whole object is dragged instead of just the text, but this then eliminates the clone functionality for some reason, even though I have helper:clone.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "ul li" ).draggable({
        appendTo: "body",
        helper: "clone"});
    $( ".day #drag" ).draggable({
        appendTo: "body"});
    $( ".day" ).droppable({
        activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
        hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
        accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            var targetElem = $(this).attr("id");

            $( this ).addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
            $( ui.draggable ).appendTo( this );
        }
    }).sortable({
        items: "li:not(.placeholder)",
        sort: function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-state-default" );
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Example column:

```
<td>
   <div id="monday" class="day monday ui-widget-content"></div>
</td>
```

Draggable element:

```
<li><div style="background-color:#<?=$bgColor?>;color:<?=$textColor?>;" id="drag" class="<?=$subject?>"><?=$row['name']?></div></li>
```

It's essentially a timetable setup tool. Thank you for the help

Here is a jsFiddle for reference: http://jsfiddle.net/x5T4h/

Comment: I don't see any error. I'am up to help you if your provide a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @Bouillou Here is my issue: http://jsfiddle.net/x5T4h/ thank you

Comment: Your fiddle is working with clone functionalities, what are you expecting?

Comment: What do you mean by the clone functionalities? Opacity?

Comment: @Bouillou as in I would theoretically be able to drag each one an infinite amount of times so I could have a column full of just English divs as an example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure that it is exactly what you want, but here is a good start for your : http://jsfiddle.net/x5T4h/2/

Basically, I removed the second `draggable` object declaration, and I added clone function to duplicate your element inside `drop` event `$( ui.draggable ).clone().appendTo( this );`

```
$(function() {
    $( "ul li" ).each(function(){
        $(this).draggable({
            helper: "clone"
        });
    });

    $( ".day" ).droppable({
        activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
        hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
        accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            var targetElem = $(this).attr("id");
            $( ui.draggable ).clone().appendTo( this );
        }
    }).sortable({
        items: "li:not(.placeholder)",
        sort: function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-state-default" );
        }
    });
});​
```

Comment: Yes this is perfect, thank you very much. You wouldn't happen to know off the top of your head if there's a way for the user to drag DIVs between columns (i.e to reorganize them) and then to be able to remove it completely from a column by dragging it away? If not it's ok don't worry about it. Thanks

Comment: Just call the draggable plugin on the cloned element. For removing, set up another drop target that checks if the element is a clone and if so, removes it from the DOM.

Comment: breaks with 1.11.0, can you let me know why it only runs with 1.8.3