# jQuery UI: Accessing the droppable that a draggable was dropped on from the `dragstop` event of the draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have a draggable and a droppable. The draggable has a helper which returns back to the location of the draggable itself whenever it is dropped. As far as I can tell, the `dragstop` event of the draggable triggers when the helper reaches the original location of the draggable. I want to do something to the droppable element that the draggable was dropped on once I drop the draggable on it. My code looks like this:

```
$(".draggable").draggable({
    helper: "clone",
    revert: true,
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        // do something with the droppable here!
    }
});
```

Is it possible to access the droppable from there? Is there a way I can do this?

I am aware of the `drop` event for the droppable, but I do actually have to either do something with the droppable from the *draggable's* stop event or I have to somehow act on both the draggable and droppable at the time that the helper returns.

Comment: var myDrop = $("#droppable").droppable(); will do your need. See if this is what you want http://jsfiddle.net/b9TdQ/3/

Comment: I don't think that'll work. I've got multiple droppables here, so I won't know which one it has been dropped on. If there's a way to work that out, that would work perfectly.

Comment: Then this links may be useful for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13056438/jquery-ui-multiple-droppable-drag-whole-div-element-clone  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985713/multiple-droppable